# When does Logan become a runner?

Tags: movie, plot-device, logans-run

I'm somewhat confused by the ambiguity in the intentions of Logan in Logan's Run (the movie). He seems genuinely interested in running as soon as he leaves his mission briefing with the supercomputer but at the same time some of his actions prove he still wishes to complete his mission. Even when he reaches the rebels checkpoint the first thing he does is signal the Sandman's headquarters for backup (after he attacked and ran away from Francis).

So when do you think he turns:

- Right after his life clock is retrograded and suspecting there is no renewal at the Carousel
- After letting the runner go in Cathedral
- After killing the Dr. in New You
- After Jessica insists she wants to go with him (right before the Sandmen's attack)
- Only after seeing the world outside

Comment: Yes. He's conflicted because the computer didn't confirm that he'd get his years back

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To carry out his mission, Logan has to become a legitimate Runner. He thus has two conflicting motivations that are, however, in practice mostly identical.

- In order to track down Sanctuary and prevent Runners from escaping, he has to gain the trust of any kind of underground railroad assisting Runners, and that means legitimately acting like a Runner and Runner sympathizer, including fighting back against the Sandmen who are tasked with killing him. If he doesn't survive, or surrenders (remember, Francis and the others aren't aware of his assignment) he can't carry out the mission. That said;
- his realization that he's probably doomed to be die sooner than he expected as the computer wasn't forthcoming that he'd get his lost time back, not to mention his realization Renewal is a fraud, means he has a vested interest in seeing if there really is a place where Runners can survive.

In both cases, the majority of his actions would be the same either way. He's obviously conflicted about it (thus the tipping off of HQ), or at least allowing training and indoctrination to influence him out of habit, but there's no single point where his motivations switch entirely one way or the other. Going outside, meeting the old man, and realizing there *is* something beyond the city, gives him a third option; he doesn't have to run from the system, he doesn't have to be part of the system, he can *change* the system.

Comment: Good point @keith-morrison. So one could interpret that even after the encounter with Box he could still be trying to play both sides and decide only after reaching Sanctuary.

Comment: I don't think it's playing both sides as much as he doesn't know what side he's on anymore. He's just trying to survive; anything beyond that he isn't really thinking about.